# GoogleMaps MyLocation Dot displays incorrectly when upgrading from 1.10.5 to 2.1.0

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ios9, ios10

After upgrading my GoogleMaps CocoaPod version from 1.10.5 to 2.1.0, I am seeing a problem with the blue 'my location' dot displayed by Google Maps. Issues with this before are the main reason I have not upgraded, but was hoping with the 2.1 release, this issue would be fixed. Apparently not.

I am running the same version of an app with the only difference being the CocoaPod version of GoogleMaps (1.10.5 vs. 2.1.0).

This is happening on all of our company devices (iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone 7+ and iPad Air).

As you can see from the first screen shot, using version 1.10.5, the blue dot is correct:

[image: ios10 screenshot]

However, same app running on 2.1.0 shows a pie-shaped white circle (no blue dot).

[image: iOS9 screenshot]

Has anyone else run into this problem? As of now, my only alternative is to go back to the 1.10.x version which works.

Comment: After further investigation, it appears to have nothing to do with iOS 9 vs. iOS 10, but more to do with GoogleMaps 1.10.5 vs. 2.1. On all of our company devices, the 'blue dot' does not appear correctly when I install 2.1 (via CocoaPods). When I revert back to 1.10.5, the blue dot is back. Clearly this has something to do with upgrading. Otherwise, I would expect more people to see this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was related to the actual version of CocoaPods itself. After upgrading from CocoaPods 1.0.0 to the latest (as of this post), 1.1.1, the problem seems to have gone away.

My best guess is that there was an issue copying over resources with the prior version of CocoaPods that was fixed with the latest release. It could also be due to the fact that the new release of CocoaPods forced a complete clean of the Pods directory and reinstalled the pods.

Regardless, the issue seems to have gone away.